# print line + next two lines with awk if next line matches

Tags: awk

I have a list like this to catch joomla version

```
./somedir/bla/old/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '24';
./somedir/bla3/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
./somedir/bla4/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
./somedir/bla5/www/w/scripts/version.php
./somedir/bla6/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
./somedir/bla7/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
```

What I want is that only the line + the two next lines are displayed if `public` is in the next line. Else line must be ignored

So the result should be:

```
./somedir/bla/old/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '24';
./somedir/bla3/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
./somedir/bla7/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
```

I have tried to use Awk and this awk script

```
BEGIN{ RS=""; FS="\n" }
 /public/ {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( ! (($i ~ /./) && ($(i+1) !~ /public/) && ($(i+2) !~ /public/) ) ) {
            print $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

But this results in:

```
./somedir/bla/old/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
./somedir/bla3/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
./somedir/bla7/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
```

I am missing the second public line with the dev_level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making this harder than it has to be by thinking about it in terms of printing what's coming next (hard to do since you haven't seen it yet!) rather than printing what came before (easy to do - just save it and print it):

```
$ awk '/public/{print p $0; p=""; next} {p=$0 ORS}' file
./somedir/bla/old/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '24';
./somedir/bla3/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
./somedir/bla7/www/libraries/cms/version/version.php
        public $RELEASE = '2.5';
        public $DEV_LEVEL = '9';
```

Any time you find yourself trying to figure out what to do with the current line based on what comes after it, take the time to rethink it in terms of doing something when you're processing the future line (so IT is then the "current" line) based on what came before it. In software and in life - seeing the future is much harder than remembering the past!

Comment: This. Twice. (thrice due to you-know-what)

Comment: Thrice the char filler.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `grep`

`grep 'public $DEV' -B 2 yourfile.txt`

from `man grep`

```
 -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
     Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  
     Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.
```

Comment: Very useful comment. This made me show leading context before my pattern. Thanks